# EVP_CIPHER_CTX in openssl 1.1.x

Tags: openssl, ssl, cryptography, open-source

error: storage size of 'ctx' isn't known
 EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;

I am getting this error with openssl -1.1.1.
Compared openssl-1.0.* and openssl-1.1.1 and this EVP_CIPHER_CTX struture has not been made opaque in openssl-1.1.1.

So why I am getting this error ?

Comment: What are you doing to generate the error? What were the steps leading up to this point?

Comment: I think you mean *has* been made opaque, see 1.1.0 `CHANGES`.

Answer (score 4):

From [OpenSSL 1.1.0 Changes](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_1.1.0_Changes):

> “All structures in libssl public header files have been removed so that they are "opaque" to library users. You should use the provided accessor functions instead.”

This (its underlying structure `evp_cipher_ctx_st`) and others are hidden from 1.1.0, they now must be accessed (create, modify, destroy) via API. To refer to such objects you now must only use a pointer to them rather than create your own instances. The advantages include encapsulation of these data types, and improved binary API compatibility.

See [`EVP_CIPHER_meth_new(3)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/EVP_CIPHER_meth_new.html).

The fine people at *Cossack Labs* have [a useful blog entry discussing the changes they needed to make](https://www.cossacklabs.com/blog/moving-to-openssl-110.html) for OpenSSL 1.1 migration.